# InputStream Http Request

Tags: android

I need to consume an HTTP services. I need to pass it 2 parameters, and I'm asking if is better to pass this parameters in the HTTP Headers as classic POST or write into BODY with InputStream. Can InputStream create problem on battery and/or performance issue?

Comment: Not much clear you issue.Can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, InputStreams are pretty efficient in Java. To answer your first question, I'm not sure what you mean by writing the parameters into the body. I prefer passing parameters using GET whenever possible because it's easiest. For example instead of posting data you can do something like:

> GET http://domain.com/mywebservice.php?param1=value1&param2=value2

Comment: 1) 
I mean that instead of passing parameters with GET i want to pass it in POST. There are any performance issue difference?

2) 
I have see this CODE:

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");
httppost.setEntity("test1");

this CODE send an string "test1" into the Body directly into the Body.

3)
There are any difference of performance in 1 and 2 example?